# Unresolved image path from the component in Laravel-mix (Reactjs & Laravel)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

I am using reactjs with the Laravel (Laravel-mix). I have my image in storage/app/public/images/slider-girl.png and referenced it on

```
 <img src="{require('/images/slider-girl.png')}" />
```

but not displaying the image.

However, I have tried to put the image in resources and public folder and I get the same response. I have tried options found here but nothing seems to work for me.

```
<img src={url('storage/app/public/images/slider-girl.png')} />
```

```
<img src="{require('/images/slider-girl.png')}" />
```

I expect the image be displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your webpack.mix.js, add

```
.setResourceRoot("/");
```

as illustrated below

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   **.setResourceRoot("/");**
```

Then just reference it as follows:

```
<img src="/images/slider-girl.png" />
```

I hope it helps